# I want to make an application that will choose the values from 1 to 9 follow by some rules In javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I want to make an application that will choose the values from 1 to 9 follow by some rules (like making a 9-digits sudoku) in javascript.

Here is my code:

```js
//This doesn't work anymore and only return value for xyz for once or return the same value every time.
var xyz = [];
var arrays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
var xy = arrays.length
setInterval(function() {
  while (xy > 0) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * xy)
    xyz.push(arrays[x])
    arrays.splice(x, 1);
    xy = xy - 1;
    console.log(xyz)
  }
  if (xyz[0] + xyz[1] + xyz[2] !== 15 && xyz[1] + xyz[4] + xyz[7] !== 15 &&
    xyz[2] + xyz[5] + xyz[8] !== 15) {
    xyz.length = 0;
    arrays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    xy = arrays.length
  }
  if (xyz[0] + xyz[1] + xyz[2] == 15 && xyz[1] + xyz[4] + xyz[7] == 15 &&
    xyz[2] + xyz[5] + xyz[8] == 15) {
    alert('it works!!!')
  }
}, 100);
```

I also try to make the `xyz[0]+xyz[1]+xyz[2] == 15 && xyz[1]+xyz[4]+xyz[7] == 15  &&xyz[2]+xyz[5]+xyz[8] == 15` be the condition for `while` loop, but the page will keep loading and doesn't work anymore.

Do anyone know how to make them work or anyone know a better algorithm?

Comment: Is this like Soduku? What are the rules and what exactly does not work?

Comment: Why the interval? You loop with while

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, it is just like the soduku. The while loop only return the value for once even though i use the while loop.I think the interval could make the while be called every 1/10 seconds, but i am wrong. I am not sure how to do that. Do you know the algorithems to make the basic 9-digits soduku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make smaller components it will be DRY and easier to test

No need for interval

Avoid negation if possible

Testing
`=== 15 && === 15 && === 15` is easier to read and understand than
`!== 15 || !== 15 || !== 15`

```js
const getXYZ = () => {
  let xyz = [];
  let  arrays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  let xy = arrays.length
  // setInterval(function() {
  while (xy > 0) {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * xy)
    xyz.push(arrays[x])
    arrays.splice(x, 1);
    xy = xy - 1;
  }
  return xyz
};

let done = false; 
while (!done) {
  const xyz = getXYZ()
  if (xyz[0] + xyz[1] + xyz[2] == 15 &&
      xyz[1] + xyz[4] + xyz[7] == 15 &&
      xyz[2] + xyz[5] + xyz[8] == 15) {
    console.log('it works!!!',xyz)
    done = true;
  }
}
```

Faster random using Fisher-Yates:

```js
const fy = (a,b,c,d) => { c=a.length;while(c)b=Math.random()*(--c+1)|0,d=a[c],a[c]=a[b],a[b]=d }


const getXYZ = () => {
  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  fy(arr)
  return arr
}

let done = false; 
while (!done) {
  const xyz = getXYZ()
  if (xyz[0] + xyz[1] + xyz[2] == 15 &&
      xyz[1] + xyz[4] + xyz[7] == 15 &&
      xyz[2] + xyz[5] + xyz[8] == 15) {
    console.log('it works!!!',xyz)
    done = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `!done` mean? Does it means  while `done = false`, it loops?

Comment: Yes. I set done to false before the loop and then when it works I set to true

Comment: See the updated script where I moved the let done to a more visible spot

Comment: I posted a shorter version using shuffle

Comment: The answer from `Yasin Br` is your answer us well, isn't it? :)

Comment: Except my shuffle is more elegant. Write-only but elegant ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is not formulated well. The opposite of the boolean expression `A and B and C` is not `not A and not B and not C`, but `not A or not B or not C`.

Also, you just need to check *one* boolean expression: use `else` to capture the opposite case.

Finally, clear the timer when you have success.

Here is a correction, which includes output to console of the number of attempts (don't use `alert`):

```js
var xyz = [];
var arrays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var xy = arrays.length;
var attempts = 1;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("attempt", attempts++);
  while (xy > 0) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * xy);
    xyz.push(arrays[x]);
    arrays.splice(x, 1);
    xy = xy - 1;
  }
  if (xyz[0] + xyz[1] + xyz[2] !== 15 || xyz[1] + xyz[4] + xyz[7] !== 15 ||
    xyz[2] + xyz[5] + xyz[8] !== 15) {
    xyz.length = 0;
    arrays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    xy = arrays.length;
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log('it works!!!');
  }
}, 50);
```

If your purpose is to create a 3x3 [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) with the digits 1..9, then there aren't that many possibilities. They are all based on this pattern:

```
    8 1 6
    3 5 7
    4 9 2
```

The pattern can be mirrored and/or turned, giving 8 solutions in total to choose from. It is probably easiest to just hardcode the 8 solutions, and randomly pick one:

```js
let solutions = [
    [8,1,6,3,5,7,4,9,2],
    [8,3,4,1,5,9,6,7,2],
    [4,3,8,9,5,1,2,7,6],
    [4,9,2,3,5,7,8,1,6],
    [2,9,4,7,5,3,6,1,8],
    [2,7,6,9,5,1,4,3,8],
    [6,7,2,1,5,9,8,3,4],
    [6,1,8,7,5,3,2,9,4]
];

let solution = solutions[Math.floor(Math.random()*8)];
console.log(solution);
```

Comment: I try to avoid negating. It is much easier to test === 15 than or not or not or not

Comment: I'm just highlighting the mistake that Asker had with boolean logic.

Comment: @trincot, thanks for pointing out my mistakes. Could I use `xyz[0] + xyz[1] + xyz[2]  || xyz[1] + xyz[4] + xyz[7]  || xyz[2] + xyz[5] + xyz[8] !== 15` to make the code shorter? Or are there some ways that i could shorten the rules, because I would like to add more rules and too many codes(rules) are very annoying. Thanks

Comment: No, but what other rules are they? Are you trying to validate a [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)?

Comment: I just wanna making a 9-digits soduku which will make the numbers in the columns, rows and diagonal lines have the same sum(15).

Comment: you are correct. So I have to write more than 10 rules to make sure the result make the numbers in the columns, rows and diagonal lines have the same sum(15). Do you know how to write a shorten version of it? Thanks

Comment: Added a section to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Another way that could be handy:**

```js
//This will fill array from 1 to 9 randomly and unique
function shuffle(array) {
  var tmp,
    current,
    top = array.length;
  if (top)
    while (--top) {
      current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
      tmp = array[current];
      array[current] = array[top];
      array[top] = tmp;
    }
  return array;
}

//one simple algorithm of getting XYZ
function getXYZ(arrays) {
  var itWorks = false;

  while (!itWorks) {
    xyz = shuffle(arrays);
    if (
      xyz[0] + xyz[1] + xyz[2] == 15 &&
      xyz[1] + xyz[4] + xyz[7] == 15 &&
      xyz[2] + xyz[5] + xyz[8] == 15
    ) {
      itWorks = true;
      return xyz;
    }
  }
}

//Test
var arrays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var xys = getXYZ(arrays);
console.log("It works! " + xys);
```

Comment: This algorithems works pretty fast. Thanks. I have a question. Does `var tmp,
    current,
    top = array.length;` define the `current and top` to   nothing  and define the `top` to `array.length`?

Comment: yeah, my friend. at first,  `tmp and current`  are undefined (because nothing is assigned to them)